# Can I have Multiple @ModelAttribute annotations in single Spring Handler Method

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Problem Statement: I have to show data from two independent models on the JSP.

Say for example There are two models: account and Student.

Attributes of Student Model are editable so, I can make use of modelattribute in the spring form and map the data from jsp to my java object.

Attributes of account are readable only, but as I have already mentioned student model in the modelattribute , in the jsp form and there can only be one modelattribute per jsp form, so I cannot assign the account to the modelattribute in Jsp spring form. In that case, how the data of the account model will be shown in the  Jsp.

Secondly, writing:
public String requestHandlingMethod(@ModelAttribute Student student, @ModelAttribute Student student)

Is this valid or not, i.e having two @ModelAttribute in Spring handler method

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a new class which has Student and Account as attributes. This way you only need one @ModelAttribute in your handler method.

```
Public Class StudentAcctWrapper{
private Student student;
private Account account;
```

The appropriate fields will be accessible in your view through an instance of StudentAcctWrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the Response @Dev, but I dont want these two models to be part of  another class. Is there any other approach for this?